# Porqué mp.search_payment devuelve resultados vacíos? (mercadopago / python)

Tags: python, mercadopago, flask

Citando el caso de ejemplo de la documentación de la API de Mercado Pago en Python:

```
@app.route("/ejemplo")
def ejemplo(**kwargs):
 #search for payments
    CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, REFRESH_TOKEN = credentials()
    mp = mercadopago.MP(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    filters = {"status": "approved"}
    searchResult = mp.search_payment(filters)
    return json.dumps(searchResult, indent=4)
```

Obtengo una cadena de `results` vacíos (luego de hacer 3 pagos con usuarios de prueba, correctamente):

```
{ "status": 200, "response": { "paging": { "total": 3, "offset": 0 }, "results": [] } }
```

¿Saben porqué está devolviendo el objeto sin los datos de pago o `results`? Estoy usando Flask.

Answer (score 0):

prueba configurando el parámetro **limit**.

```
    filters = {
        "status": "approved",
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 10
    }
```

Comment: Mismo resultado con o sin 'limit' :(

Comment: Hola jose.. Gracias por el aporte. Tu respuesta se reporto como de baja calidad, ya que no dices que beneficios o cosas hace agregar ese parametro. Mas alla del comentario de OP que dice que no le sirve, porque pensas que es la solucion?

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar alguna explicación mínima para evitar los votos negativos

Comment: Fue un error mio, lo siento! La respuesta de Damián debería funcionar ya que el método search_payment recibe 3 parámetros ($filters,$offset,$limit).

Answer (score 0):

Me pasó lo mismo en php.
Si bien voy a comentar sobre mi experiencia en php, muy probablemente suceda lo mismo en Python.
El problema es que si bien en la documentación dice que el valor por defecto de limit es 100, en el código lo establece en 0. Nótese que "limit" no es un atributo de filters, es un parámetro aparte (es por eso que la respuesta anterior no te funcionó)

**Solución 1:**
Cambia

```
searchResult = mp.search_payment(filters)
```

por

```
searchResult = mp.search_payment(filters,0,100)
```

**Solución 2:**
cambiar la definición del método search_payment. El parámetro limit debe tener 0 como predeterminado, pon 100 u otro número.